# I need to Get my changed SSID and Password in my Serial monitor

Tags: wifi, nodemcu

I have this(Wifi Manager - Autoconnect IP) program run in my arduino IDE. And I get the output in serial monitor as this

[image: Serial Monitor Output]

Can Anyone help me in displaying my SSID and PASS in this serial monitor output?

My code is this

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>          //https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino

//needed for library
#include <DNSServer.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
#include <WiFiManager.h>         //https://github.com/tzapu/WiFiManager


void setup() {
    // put your setup code here, to run once:
    Serial.begin(115200);

    //WiFiManager
    //Local intialization. Once its business is done, there is no need to keep it around
    WiFiManager wifiManager;
    //reset saved settings
    //wifiManager.resetSettings();

    //set custom ip for portal
    //wifiManager.setAPStaticIPConfig(IPAddress(10,0,1,1), IPAddress(10,0,1,1), IPAddress(255,255,255,0));

    //fetches ssid and pass from eeprom and tries to connect
    //if it does not connect it starts an access point with the specified name
    //here  "AutoConnectAP"
    //and goes into a blocking loop awaiting configuration
    wifiManager.autoConnect("AutoConnectAP");
    //or use this for auto generated name ESP + ChipID
    //wifiManager.autoConnect();


    //if you get here you have connected to the WiFi
    Serial.println("connected...yeey :)");
}

void loop() {
    // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}

I am using WIFImanager library example - Autoconnect
```

Comment: https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/latest/esp8266wifi/station-class.html#ssid

Comment: Thank you for the link juraj.. btw where should I add that line of code. In the main program or in the header file??

Answer (score 1):

You can use functions SSID() and psk() which are available on the WiFi object as documented [here](https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/latest/esp8266wifi/station-class.html#ssid).

Put these lines in setup() after `wifiManager.autoConnect`:

```
Serial.print("SSID: ");
Serial.println(WiFi.SSID());
Serial.print("psk: ");
Serial.println(WiFi.psk());
```